# Android studio import module button missing

Tags: android, eclipse, module, android-studio, missing-features

I've got a long history with Eclipse, but I wanted to try Android Studio. So I created new project and now I want to add SlidingMenu library to it. I found some tutorials whose say to go to Project structure, click plus button and select Import module.

But there is no Import module option, when I click plus then New Module window pops up. I'm currenty using Android studio v0.3.6. Is now proccess to import module different?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Import Module feature has been removed for Gradle-based projects because it previously didn't do the right thing with your Gradle build files and it would put your project in a confusing state; it will be re-enabled when it's properly implemented. The bug tracking it is at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62122.

In the meantime, to add a module, you need to write a `build.gradle` file for it by hand, add a reference to the module to your `settings.gradle` file, and if the project is still open in Android Studio after you make the changes, click on the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button in the toolbar.

If you're not familiar with Gradle, you can get docs on the particulars of Android Gradle projects at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide.